# How can I define an array inside a PHP class scope in PHP4

Tags: php, php4

I need to define a *constant* array within the scope of an class, which is to be used *statically* (i.e. I am not creating an instance of the class). Here is the sample code which works in PHP5, but not in PHP4:

```
class MyTest {
    static $arr = array(100, 200);
    function test() {
        print_r(MyTest::$arr);
    }
}

MyTest::test();
```

How can I change this code so it works in PHP4 (4.4.9-pl0-gentoo)?

Remarks:

- It has to work in PHP4.
- I need to access the array preferrably in a static manner, without creating an instance. But this requirement could be dropped.
- I cannot use `GLOBALS` as the code has to work within `phpunit` unit-testing. When doing so, an array defined as `GLOBAL` in the header of the file is not seen within the unittest.
- I want to define the array (containing constant values) outside the function it is being used. But if no other possibility exists to solve my question, this requirement could be dropped as well.

Comment: Any special PHP4 Revision?

Comment: If you're referring to phpunit (i.e. unit tests) - why use `static` at all? It makes testing more difficult.

Comment: PHP4? Really?? What kind of insanity brought you to having to meet that as a requirement in 2013? I hope you're charging them a lot for this.

Comment: @Spudley: I know its insane. Even worse: The code mixes PHP4 and PHP5 code! But unfortunately this is not my decision...

Comment: If it's on a public webserver, then whoever is making the decision needs to be given a swift hit with the proverbial clue-bat. The security implications of running PHP4 these days are scary. I'd go so far as to say it's being willfully negligent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyTest {
    public function getArray() {
        return array(100, 200);
    }
}
```

Not pretty, but you can simply call `MyTest::getArray()` without creating an instance (or `$this->getArray()` from inside the class) to retrieve the data.